# Effect of column normalization on maximum diagonal entry

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-analysis

Let $\mathbf{A}$ be a $M\times N$ complex matrix, and $\bar{\mathbf{A}}$ be constituted by normalizing each column of $\mathbf{A}$. Therefore, we have
$$\mathbf{A}=\bar{\mathbf{A}}\mathbf{\Gamma},$$
where $\mathbf{\Gamma}=\mathrm{diag}(\|\mathbf{a}_n\|)$ is a diagonal matrix and $\mathbf{a}_n$ is the $n$th column of matrix $\mathbf{A}$. Is there any relation between these two following quantities:
\begin{align}
&\max_m \quad [\mathbf{A}\mathbf{A}^\mathrm{H}]_{m,m},\\
&\max_m \quad [\bar{\mathbf{A}}\bar{\mathbf{A}}^\mathrm{H}]_{m,m},
\end{align}
where $[\cdot]_{m,m}$ is the $m$th diagonal entry of $\mathbf{A}$ and $(\cdot)^{\mathrm{H}}$ denotes conjugate transpose operation.

Answer (score 1):

Let $a_{m,n}$ be the elements of matrix $\mathbf{A}$. Then, we have
\begin{align}
\beta_{\max}&=\max_m \quad [\mathbf{A}\mathbf{A}^\mathrm{H}]_{m,m}=\max_m \sum_{n=1}^{N}|a_{m,n}|^2\\
\bar{\beta}_{\max}&=\max_m \quad [\bar{\mathbf{A}}\bar{\mathbf{A}}^\mathrm{H}]_{m,m}=\max_m \sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{|a_{m,n}|^2}{\|\mathbf{a}_n\|^2}.
\end{align}
Therefore, by defining $\alpha_{\max}=\max_n \|\mathbf{a}_n\|$ and $\alpha_{\min}=\min_n \|\mathbf{a}_n\|$, we have
\begin{align}
\bar{\beta}_{\max}&=\max_m \sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{|a_{m,n}|^2}{\|\mathbf{a}_n\|^2}\\
&\leq \max_m \sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{|a_{m,n}|^2}{\alpha_{\min}^2}\\
&=\frac{\beta_{\max}}{\alpha_{\min}^2}.
\end{align}
Similarly, we obtain
\begin{align}
\bar{\beta}_{\max}\geq\frac{\beta_{\max}}{\alpha_{\max}^2}.
\end{align}